# why egrep's stdout did not go through pipe?

Tags: python, shell, pipe, grep

i got a weird problem regarding egrep and pipe

I tried to filter a stream containing some lines who start with a topic name, such as 
"TICK:this is a tick message\n"

When I try to use egrep to filter it :
./stream_generator | egrep 'TICK' | ./topic_processor
It seems that the topic_processor never receives any messages

However, when i use the following python script:
./stream_generator | python filter.py --topics TICK | ./topic_processor
everything looks to be fine.

I guess there need to be a 'flush' mechanism for egrep as well, is this correct?

Can anyone here give me a clue? Thanks a million

```
import sys
from optparse import OptionParser

if __name__ == '__main__':

    parser = OptionParser()

    parser.add_option("-m", "--topics",
                  action="store", type="string", dest="topics")

    (opts, args) = parser.parse_args()

    topics = opts.topics.split(':')

    while True:
        s = sys.stdin.readline()
        for each in topics:
            if s[0:4] == each:
                sys.stdout.write(s)
                sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: What do you get if you just do `./stream_generator | egrep 'TICK'` ? Do you get the expecting results output on the console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you allowed the command `./stream_generator | egrep 'TICK' | ./topic_processor` to run to completion?  If the command has completed without producing output then the problem does not lie with buffering since, upon the termination of  `./stream_generator`, `egrep` will flush any of *its* buffers and in turn terminate.

Now, it is true that `egrep` will use heavy buffering when not outputting directly to a terminal (i.e. when outputting to a pipe or file), and it may appear *for a while* that `egrep` produces no output if not enough data has accumulated in `egrep`'s buffer to warrant a flush.  This behaviour can be changed in GNU `egrep` by using the `--line-buffered` option:

```
./stream_generator | egrep --line-buffered 'TICK' | ./topic_processor
```